# Is it possible to concatenate itemized lists?

Tags: macros, formatting, environments, itemize

I am currently keeping track of my research / tasks to do in a LaTeX lab journal. The organization of each day in the Latex code is essentially like the following toy example:

```
\chapter{Saturday, 2nd February 2021}

\begin{importanttodo}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Clean the house
    \item Pet the Dog
\end{itemize}
\end{importanttodo}

Description of Research: Today I though it would be good to pet the dog. Also the house is dusty...

\chapter{Sunday, 3rd February 2021}

\begin{importanttodo}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Calculate the Mass of the Sun
\end{itemize}
\end{importanttodo}

Description of Research: I wonder how heavy the sun is...
```

Here {importanttodo} just formats the interior {itemize} in a nice way.

I was wondering what the easiest way would be to define a command which I could call at the beginning of the document, that would concatenate all items in the todo lists scattered throughout the research journal and give a collective to do list.

If this is possible, it is simple to also add an optional parameter to my todo list which ignores certain todo list tasks which have been completed. In the document this might look something like the following:

```
\chapter{Saturday, 2nd March 2020}

\begin{importanttodo}
    \item Clean the house
    \item[Done] pet the dog
\end{importanttodo}

Description of Research: Today I though it would be good to pet the dog. Also the house is dusty...

\chapter{Sunday, 3rd February 2021}

\begin{importanttodo}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Calculate the Mass of the Sun
\end{itemize}
\end{importanttodo}

Description of Research: I wonder how heavy the sun is...
```

Thus "Clean the House" would be added to the todo list, but not "Pet the Dog".

Finally, is it possible for this concatenated todo list to also include dates for the task. Ideally this collected todo list would look something like the following:

```
TO DO LIST:

(Saturday, 2nd February 2021)
* Clean the House
(Sunday, 3rd February 2021)
* Calculate the Mass of the Sun
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106576/collect-the-input-of-all-todo-commands-used-in-the-document-at-the-end and possibly this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes